# Totem pole PFC control

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control, power-factor-correction

I found a figure that discusses how to control S3 and S4 of the totem pole PFC.

Please refer to the image below.

However, I couldn't find any information regarding the control method used in this circuit.

Would anyone happen to know how this control circuit works? Alternatively, could you provide me with the name of this control circuit or any research paper that I could refer to?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add a link to the site in which you found those diagrams. What is particularly problematic to you regarding them?

Comment: It seems rather redundant. As Andy says, you may find your answer in whatever supporting information they went with; which may include an answer such as "the author doesn't know what they're doing".

Comment: The schematics look like they were created in MS-Paint and the lack of professionalism would suggest to me that the design will be very poor quality too. SE policy is that you must attribute the work of others. Generally a hyperlink to the source of the material will suffice.

Comment: @Andyaka 
These figure are from my friends, but he doesn't know the link, they only get the figures like I posted. 
Sorry about that.

Comment: @TimWilliams 
I will try to find the information about the figures, thanks.

Comment: @Transistor 

I think the figure were created in MS-Paint

Comment: It is a schematic coming from PSIM and probably rearranged to make it colorful. Not for the best I result I agree : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have described a totem-pole PFC (TPPFC) in my recent [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20PFC.pdf) on power factor correction. The below figure represents the basic structure in which you can see two legs: a fast leg, on the left, to which the inductor connects and a slow leg, in the right which rectifies the ac mains. The slow leg can be supplemented with synchronous switches to further improve efficiency:

[image]

In a classical PFC, the bipolar input sine wave is transformed into a unipolar positive waveform. This voltage is feeding a boost converter in which a transistor and a diode chop the pulsating waveform and elevate it to a higher dc output voltage. In this mode, each switch has a fixed role and keeps it during the two polarity of the input cycle: switching for the power transistor, freewheeling for the boost diode.

In a TPPFC, it is different since the two active switches in the fast leg alternately play the role of the switch or the (synchronous) rectifier. As shown in the below picture, when the input polarity is positive, the low-side transistor is actuated as in a classical boost converter and the upper switch plays the role of the diode. On the contrary, when the input polarity reverses, the upper-side transistor becomes the switching component while the low-side transistor is freewheeling the inductor current. Because you need to switch fast and avoid recovery losses, this TPPFC structure has gained in popularity owing to GaN and SiC transistors.

[image]

Since the input polarity must be known, you need a dedicated circuit to observe it and instruct the switches what role to play, switch or synchronous diodes. This is the goal of the logic gates and comparators driving the switches in your circuit.

The control law to generate a low input current is the same whether you talk about a classical single-switch structure or a TPPFC. The drive management however differs and can be quite complicated to prevent misfiring of the switches, particularly in surges and distorted waveforms. Also, the switching around zero volt can be touchy and various algorithms exist to limit crossover spikes and distortion. See this [paper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt650/slyt650.pdf?ts=1683225044831&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.fr%252F) for some good hints.

As part of my 80+ ready-made [simulation templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf), I have built a TPPFC which is using a very simple scheme - 1-cycle control - described by Dr. Ben-Yaakov in [1998](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/679011). The circuit is shown below:

[image]

The subcircuit internals are simplified and would obviously require some robust circuitry as found in commercial circuits. The goal here is to simply illustrate the TPPFC operation:

[image]

The circuit simulates in a few seconds and delivers the below waveforms for a 1-kW application supplied from a 100-V rms source:

[image]

The circuit is stabilized with the automated macro for a few Hz crossover.

Comment: Hi @Verbal Kint,
Could you clarify if the control method of this circuit is the same as the one described in the article? I did not see Vac*Iac mentioned in your response. Or is it that the control method described in the article is not suitable for TPPFC application?
Thanks for your great answer.

Comment: There is no input voltage sensing in this approach and thus, no need for a multiplier. The heart of this simple embodiment is the modulator around G1. You will find more information in this [patent document](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/c5/92/3b/c334b35daab704/US6307361.pdf).